# Compojure not getting request body

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have an application using Compojure with this sort of endpoint

```
(defroutes routes
  (POST "/api/v1/echo" req (str req))

(def http-handler
  (reload/wrap-reload (wrap-defaults #'routes api-defaults)))

(defn run-web-server []
    (run-jetty http-handler {:port 10555 :join? false}))
```

When I try this curl request

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:10555/api/v1/echo -d '{"hello": "world"}'
```

I get this response

```
{:ssl-client-cert nil, :remote-addr "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1", :params {}, :route-params {}, :headers {"accept" "*/*", "user-agent" "curl/7.43.0", "content-type" "application/json", "content-length" "18", "host" "localhost:10555"}, :server-port 10555, :content-length 18, :form-params {}, :query-params {}, :content-type "application/json", :character-encoding nil, :uri "/api/v1/echo", :server-name "localhost", :query-string nil, :body #object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput 0x4317e5fa "org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@4317e5fa"], :scheme :http, :request-method :post}%
```

What I'm expecting to see is `{"hello", "world"}` *somewhere* in that response, but it's not there. I see there is `:body HttpInput`, but when I try `(prn (-> req :body .read))` it outputs `123`. Because `(= "{\"hello\", \"world\"}" 123) => false`, I'm a little lost about what to try next.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:10555/api/v1/echo -d "foo=1&bar=2"` does work as expected and returns `:params {:foo "1", :bar "2"}`, but I'd rather submit json. I know I could use compojure-api probably, but I'm curious why this behaves this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [ring-json](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json) middleware, particularly `wrap-json-body` to parse json parameters:

> The wrap-json-body middleware will parse the body of any request with a JSON content-type into a Clojure data structure, and assign it to the :body key.
>
> This is the preferred way of handling JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [wrap-json-params](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json#wrap-json-params) middleware in your handler.